# What is the purpose of the F# string concatenation operator ^

Tags: .net, f#

I was reading through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings) and hit this paragraph

> There are two ways to concatenate strings: by using the + operator or by using the ^ operator. The + operator maintains compatibility with the .NET Framework string handling features.

I bashed it into my linqpad, and it runs ok, but I do get a warning

> This construct is for ML compatibility. Consider using the '+' operator instead

Had a search around the web for further detail but came up with nix.

Can anyone elaborate on the ^'s intended function ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer - use `+` rather than `^` like the warning suggests, the operators are interchangeable.

The longer answer: looking into FSharp.Core, you will find that both of those operators are inlined and defer to `System.String.Concat`.

See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/e835edf083f03c325626fb656c356295c344a75b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L417) for `^`:

```
let inline (^)     (x:string) (y:string) = System.String.Concat(x,y)
```

and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/e835edf083f03c325626fb656c356295c344a75b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3516) for `+`:

```
let inline (+) (x: ^T) (y: ^U) : ^V = 
    AdditionDynamic<(^T),(^U),(^V)>  x y 
    ...
    when ^T : string      and ^U : string     = 
       (# "" (System.String.Concat((# "" x : string #),(# "" y : string #))) : ^T #)
```

with the `+` definition being more complicated, but boiling down to the same thing.

`^` seems to be one of many (and in practice obsolete) constructs in F# that were adopted from [OCaml](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-caml-light/node14.17.html) at a time when ease of porting OCaml code to F# was considered an important selling point for the language:

```
value prefix ^ : string -> string -> string
s1 ^ s2 returns a fresh string containing the concatenation of the strings s1 and s2.
```

I can't really remember ever seeing code using `^` in practice, and wouldn't be able to tell F# had this operator if you asked me.

Comment: Do you take the ML in the warning to stand for 'Meta Language" or "Machine Learning" or something else ?

Comment: Definitely the first one, ML as in family of languages F# belongs to.